# Unable to seperate 'tif' extension from file name, all other extensions work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file input with the ID 'submission-file'. 
In the code below I am splitting the extension from the filename into the variable 'type'.

For some reason, all the filetypes except 'tif' work. I have successfully 'gif, png, jpg, jpeg' all being separated and stored, but tif fails.

I set up the below example to test. When a .tif file is entered, the console log reads nothing. The other file types that I have tested (shown above) all display correctly.

I have tried a several over approaches to try and get the extension, but tif wont show on any.

Can anyone tell me how to get around this?

```
   var type = $('#submission-file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

   console.log(type);
```

Comment: are you sure it's JUST tif, and not all non-standardish image types? e.g. what happens if you try using a .txt or somethign else non-imageish?

Comment: what do you have in `#submission-file` ? A string such as `var type = "file.tif".split('.').pop().toLowerCase();` will return an extension, so it does not look like your logic is faulty.

Comment: Lucky guess : for the tif files, there is a `.` in the file name.

Comment: Okay, I just tried some other filetypes, and your right, things limke .sql don't show up either.

Comment: @Ryan yes, thats exactly what I have. But it appears it doesn't work on certain file types. What I need to know is why.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Hmm, shouldn't be a problem, as the string is taking anything after the '.'.

Comment: works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LEzDX/

Comment: @profitehlolz Your right... must be something in my script then...